# Inserir link clicável em um mapa com JSON

Tags: json

estou tentando montar um mapa do estado do Espírito Santo, aonde você clica na cidade e consegue acessar o conteúdo referente a cada município. 
Eu achei um framework (FusionCharts) que eu consegui fazer isto, mas não consigo passar acertar como eu passo os valores para que cada cidade no mapa seja clicável. 
Link: (http://www.danieldias.info/projetos/acidentesflorestais/)

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.fusioncharts.com/fusioncharts/latest/fusioncharts.js"></script>
<!-- Including the map renderer file -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.fusioncharts.com/fusioncharts/latest/fusioncharts.maps.js "></script>
<!-- Including the map definition file -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="fusioncharts.espiritosanto.js"></script>
<!-- Including the fusion theme -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.fusioncharts.com/fusioncharts/latest/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    FusionCharts.ready(function() {
        var annualPopulation = new FusionCharts({
            "type": "maps/espiritosanto",
            "renderAt": "chart-container",
            "width": "100%",
            "height": "430",
            "dataFormat": "json",
            "dataSource": {
                // Map Configuration
                "chart": {
                    //"caption": "Índice de Acidentes Florestais no Espirito Santo",
                    //"subcaption": " 1955-2015",
                    "numbersuffix": "%",
                    "includevalueinlabels": "1",
                    "labelsepchar": ": ",
                    "entityFillHoverColor": "#27ae60",
                    "theme": "fusion"
                },
                // Aesthetics; ranges synced with the slider
                /*"colorrange": {
                    "minvalue": "0",
                    "code": "#27ae60",
                    "gradient": "1",
                    "color": [{
                        "minvalue": "0.5",
                        "maxvalue": "1.0",
                        "color": "#FFD74D"
                    }, {
                        "minvalue": "1.0",
                        "maxvalue": "2.0",
                        "color": "#FB8C00"
                    }, {
                        "minvalue": "2.0",
                        "maxvalue": "3.0",
                        "color": "#E65100"
                    }]
                },*/

                "data": [{
                    "id":"AC",
                    "label":"Afonso Cláudio",
                    "link" : "estado.html"

                },  ]

            }
        });
        annualPopulation.render();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Importante [edt] e reduzir o problema a um [mcve] da dúvida específica, sempre levando em conta o [escopo do site](/help/on-topic). Links para entender melhor o funcionamento do SOpt: [Tour], [Ask], [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/70) e [Help].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o callback do componente após ele ser renderizado:

```
annualPopulation.render(function(){
   // callback
});
```

Dentro do callback você irá percorrer todos os `path` criando um `onclick` para cada um:

```
annualPopulation.render(function(){
  var paths = document.querySelectorAll("#chart-container path");
  for(let x=0; x < paths.length; x++){
     paths[x].onclick = function(){
        var area = document.querySelector(".fc__tooltip").textContent;
        alert(area);
     }
  }
});
```

O elemento com a class `.fc__tooltip` possui o nome da área onde o cursor está posicionado, e você pode pegar esse nome com `.textContent`.

Para alterar o cursor do mouse, use a propriedade abaixo no CSS:

```
#chart-container path{
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

**Veja:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#chart-container path{
   cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>T</title>
    <!-- Including the fusioncharts core library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.fusioncharts.com/fusioncharts/latest/fusioncharts.js"></script>
    <!-- Including the map renderer file -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.fusioncharts.com/fusioncharts/latest/fusioncharts.maps.js "></script>
    <!-- Including the map definition file -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fusioncharts.espiritosanto.js"></script>
    <!-- Including the fusion theme -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.fusioncharts.com/fusioncharts/latest/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        FusionCharts.ready(function() {
           
           
            var annualPopulation = new FusionCharts({
                "type": "maps/espiritosanto",
                "renderAt": "chart-container",
                "width": "800",
                "height": "550",
                "dataFormat": "json",
                "dataSource": {
                    // Map Configuration
                    "chart": {
                        "caption": "Índice de Acidentes Florestais no Espirito Santo",
                        "subcaption": " 1955-2015",
                        "numbersuffix": "%",
                        "includevalueinlabels": "1",
                        "labelsepchar": ": ",
                        "entityFillHoverColor": "#FFF9C4",
                        "theme": "fusion"
                    },
                    // Aesthetics; ranges synced with the slider
                    /*"colorrange": {
                        "minvalue": "0",
                        "code": "#FFE0B2",
                        "gradient": "1",
                        "color": [{
                            "minvalue": "0.5",
                            "maxvalue": "1.0",
                            "color": "#FFD74D"
                        }, {
                            "minvalue": "1.0",
                            "maxvalue": "2.0",
                            "color": "#FB8C00"
                        }, {
                            "minvalue": "2.0",
                            "maxvalue": "3.0",
                            "color": "#E65100"
                        }]
                    },*/
                    // Source data as JSON --> id represents countries of world.
                    "data": [{
                        "id": "NA",
                        "value": ".82",
                        "showLabel": "1"
                    }, {
                        "id": "SA",
                        "value": "2.04",
                        "showLabel": "1"
                    }, {
                        "id": "AS",
                        "value": "1.78",
                        "showLabel": "1"
                    }, {
                        "id": "EU",
                        "value": ".40",
                        "showLabel": "1"
                    }, {
                        "id": "AF",
                        "value": "2.58",
                        "showLabel": "1"
                    }, {
                        "id": "AU",
                        "value": "1.30",
                        "showLabel": "1"
                    }]
                }
            });
            annualPopulation.render(function(){
              var paths = document.querySelectorAll("#chart-container path");
              for(let x=0; x < paths.length; x++){
                 paths[x].onclick = function(){
                    var area = document.querySelector(".fc__tooltip").textContent;
                    alert(area);
                 }
              }
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="chart-container">FusionMaps XT will load map here!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Eu copiei o trecho do código para testar deu muito certo, mas está ocorrendo um erro que quando eu apago algum trecho do código que não tem nada haver como o título, subtitulo ou aquela barrinha que fica em baixo o código de renderização que vocÊ enviou deixa de funcionar,  porque?

Comment: Depende de qual parte vc está apagando.

Comment: O caption,subcaption e o color range

Comment: Aí eu já não sei. Eu apenas respondi usando o código que vc colocou na pergunta :D

Comment: No código que eu postei tem algumas partes que estão marcadas como comentário vc consegue fazer com estas partes ainda como comentário?

Comment: Sim, era só mudar o seletor. Alterei a resposta.

Comment: Poderia tentar por gentileza.

Comment: Já alterei a resposta comentando o colorrange e está funcionando. Como eu disse, era spo alterar o seletor para `"#chart-container path"`.

Comment: Muitissimo obrigado, resolveu perfeitamente o problema.

Comment: Amigo, eu consigo definir uma cor para cada cidade?

Comment: Talvez seja possível.

Comment: Qual elemento que eu alteraria a cor no Java script? Eu percebi no código um stroke que contém a cor cinza.